# Relative links in Jekyll on Github Pages and localhost are not working correctly

Tags: javascript, gulp, jekyll, github-pages

I use Gulp to run Jekyll. My setup works fine on localhost, but when I introduce Github Pages relative links stop working. I use [gulp-gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gh-pages) npm package to push `_site` contents to `gh-pages` branch.

Contents of `gulpfile.js` related to Jekyll and Github Pages:

```
var browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var runSequence  = require('run-sequence');
var ghPages      = require('gulp-gh-pages');
var gutil        = require('gulp-util');
var run          = require('gulp-run');
var del          = require('del');

gulp.task('build:jekyll', function(callback) {
    var shellCommand = 'jekyll build --incremental';

    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(run(shellCommand))
        .on('error', gutil.log);

    callback();
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del(['_site', 'assets']);
});

// [`build:scripts`, `build:styles`, `build:images`] is removed from the runSequence example for MVP
gulp.task('build:prod', function(callback) {
    return runSequence('clean', 'build:jekyll', callback)
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('deploy',['build:prod'], function(){
    return gulp.src('./_site/**/*')
        .pipe(ghPages());
});
```

Contents of `config.yml`:

```
baseurl: /

collections:
  pages:
    output: true
    permalink: /:title/

exclude: ["_assets", "gulpfile.js", "node_modules", "package.json", "package-lock.json", ".jekyll-metadata"]
```

Reference to assets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}assets/styles/main.min.css">
```

Front matter on every page inside `_pages` directory:

```
---
layout: page
title: Title
description: Awesome description
image: https://source.unsplash.com/random/?water
---
```

Here is the link to my Github repository with full source code: https://github.com/alljamin/portfolio

How can I configure Gulp and Jekyll so all the relative links work both locally and on Github Pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try : "`baseurl: /portfolio`"

Generate url with `{{site.baseurl}}/path/to/res` or `{{ "/path/to/res" | prepend: site.baseurl }}`.

Comment: Github Pages now work, but locally some of the assets will not load. Is there any chance to have a setup what works both locally and on Github Pages? Or, do I need two separate `_config.yml` files, one for development and one for production?

Comment: @JoostS what you are saying is that you do not have any separation between local development and production (Github Pages)? How you do handle relative urls then (`baseurl` will differ)?

Comment: Locally I run on localhost:4000 and on Github Pages I run the site on a custom domain name. Therefore the site is always in the root. That works like a charm.

Comment: Pointing your browser to **http://localhost:4000/portfolio** should work. If not, look at generated urls, it can be a slash problem or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the @david-jacquel answer I was able to find a way to successfully run localhost and Github Pages environments via separate Gulp tasks.

Contents of `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('build:jekyll:dev', function(callback) {
    var shellCommand = 'jekyll build --incremental --baseurl "" ';

    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(run(shellCommand))
        .on('error', gutil.log);

    callback();
});

gulp.task('build:jekyll:prod', function(callback) {
    var shellCommand = 'jekyll build --incremental';

    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(run(shellCommand))
        .on('error', gutil.log);

    callback();
});
```

The `build:jekyll:dev` task will overwrite the `_config.yml` baseurl to `""`. So I can do something like this:

```
gulp.task('build:dev', function(callback) {
    return runSequence('clean', ['build:scripts', 'build:styles', 'build:images'], 'build:jekyll:dev', callback)
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('build:prod', function(callback) {
    return runSequence('clean', ['build:scripts', 'build:styles', 'build:images'], 'build:jekyll:prod', callback)
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('serve', ['build:dev'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "_site"
        },
        ghostMode: false, 
        logFileChanges: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        open: true        
    });
    gulp.watch(...);
});

gulp.task('deploy',['build:prod'], function(){
    return gulp.src('./_site/**/*')
        .pipe(ghPages());
});
```